# Setting checkbox dynamically from sqlite in a Fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, checkbox, android-fragments

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to store and display checkboxes in a listview.

Right now I have the code in the getView method:

```
@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            //final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
            }
            ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_img);

            cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk_box_griditem);


            if(photos.get(position).getIshidden()){
                cb.setChecked(false);
            }else{
                cb.setChecked(true);
            }


            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    MySQLiteHelper db = MySQLiteHelper.getInstance(getActivity());
                    Log.d("checkbox", "status: " + photos.get(position).getIshidden());

                    if (isChecked) {
                        photos.get(position).setIshidden(true);
                        cb.setChecked(true);
                        Log.d("checkbox", "isChecked");
                        db.updatePhoto(photos.get(position));

                    } else {
                        photos.get(position).setIshidden(false);
                        cb.setChecked(false);
                        Log.d("checkbox", "isCheckedelse");
                        db.updatePhoto(photos.get(position));
                    }

                }
            });

            imageLoader.displayImage(imgUrls[position], img, options, animateFirstListener);

            //img.setImageResource(mImgRes);
            return convertView;
        }
```

The db helper takes a photo object as an argument and updates the row if it exists. So right now I update the current photo object `isHidden()` to be true or false then pass the updated object to db helper.

The physical database seems to be updating correctly. However a problem occurs when the checkboxes state is being set. The checkboxes seem to be randomly set as checked or unchecked.

Also I feel like doing this in the getView is cpu greedy but am not sure how else to do this.

Comment: You do not have to set the OnCheckedChangeListener every time getView is called. One for every checkbox is enough. -> I see it, you need a new Listener because you reference the position in the listener.

Comment: To what class does this `getView` method belong? To an adapter?
And it would be nice to know whats your goal is.What is this `photos` object?

Comment: Its from a custom listview adapter `private class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter`

Comment: Ok, mmhh... Why are you setting the checkbox in the Listener? `cb.setChecked(true);`
It's already set, or do i miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First **remove cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener**...You do not need to set the OnCheckedChangeListener every time getView is called.you have already written the below code which will set check-box state(checked or unchecked) when list-view loads.

```
if(photos.get(position).getIshidden())
cb.setChecked(false);
else
cb.setChecked(true);
```

Now set onItemClick listener as below on list view :

```
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) 
        {

            MySQLiteHelper db = MySQLiteHelper.getInstance(getActivity());
            Log.d("checkbox", "status: " + photos.get(position).getIshidden());

            if(photos.get(position).getIshidden())
            {
                ((CheckBox)arg0.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.chk_box_griditem)).setChecked(true);
                photos.get(position).setIshidden(false);
                db.updatePhoto(photos.get(position));

            }   
            else
            {
                ((CheckBox)arg0.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.chk_box_griditem)).setChecked(false);
                photos.get(position).setIshidden(true);
                db.updatePhoto(photos.get(position));

            }

        }


    });
```

by that way you can check or uncheck the check-box and at the same time the check-box state(checked or unchecked) will be saved in your database.

I hope it will work.If not let me know..:)

Answer (score 1):

When you are initializing your checkbox you set the Check state to false if the image is hidden.

```
if(photos.get(position).getIshidden()){
    cb.setChecked(false);
}else{
    cb.setChecked(true);
}
```

But in the Listener you set the image to hide when the checkbox is checked.

```
if (isChecked) {
    photos.get(position).setIshidden(true);
...
```

This is actually the inverse. You are probably disturbed by that.
And you do not have to set the checked state again in the listener.

So your code in the listener could look like this:

```
if (isChecked) {
     photos.get(position).setIshidden(false);
     Log.d("checkbox", "isChecked");
     db.updatePhoto(photos.get(position));

} else {
     photos.get(position).setIshidden(true);
     Log.d("checkbox", "isCheckedelse");
     db.updatePhoto(photos.get(position));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Do not set the checkbox in the listener

2) Attach the listener in the checkbox only if convertView is null (i.e. when inflating). When you get your view from the convertview it has its listener set already.

Answer (score 0):

**Change and then log**.  OnCheckedChange you can get away with no if statements and just use the boolean.  You don't need to set the value in of the check box in the checkedchanged listener.  Intialize db in onResume so it's available no telling how many times a user will click something and the db initialization will slow things down.

```
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                    photos.get(position).setIshidden(isChecked);
                    db.updatePhoto(photos.get(position));
                    Log.d("checkbox", isChecked.toString());
            }
        });



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if (db==null) {
        db = MySQLiteHelper.getInstance(getActivity());
    }
}
```